# Using Calculus, find the point on circle $(x-3)^2+(y-1)^2=16$ that is closest to arbitrary point $(-2,2)$ in $x-y$ plane that is not on the circle.

Tags: calculus, circles, maxima-minima, plane-geometry

**Problem**

> Using Calculus, find the point on the circle $(x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 16$ that is closest to arbitrary point $(-2,2)$ in the $x-y$ plane that is not on the circle.

**My Attempt :**
Attached images show the derivation from which I took the first derivative. I took the derivative of what I believed to be the distance formula from the point to a point on the circle. Please advise.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4):

The line that passes through $(—2,—2)$ and the center of the circle intersects the circle at the closest and the farthest point.

Comment: I agree. When I was teaching, I always told my students that a non-Calculus solution to a problem would always be sound, and often better and clearer as well.

Answer (score 3):

You want to find the point (x,y) on the circle that minimizes

$$D(x) = \sqrt{(x+2)^2+(y+2)^2} \tag{1.}$$

where $$(x-3)^2 + (y-1)^2 = 16\tag{2.}$$

Taking the (implicit) derivative of $(2.)$, we find

\begin{align}
   2(x-3) + 2(y-1) y' &= 0 \\
   y' &= -\dfrac{x-3}{y-1}
\end{align}

We need to solve

\begin{align}
   D'(x) &= 0 \\
   \dfrac{2(x+2)+2(y+2)y'}{2\sqrt{(x+2)^2+(y+2)^2}} &= 0 \\
   (x+2)+(y+2)y' &= 0 \\
   y' &= -\dfrac{x+2}{y+2} \\
   \dfrac{x-3}{y-1} &= \dfrac{x+2}{y+2} \\
   xy-3y+2x-6 &= xy-x+2y-2 \\
   3x-5y &= 4 \\
   y &= \frac 35x - \frac 45
\end{align}

Substituting this into $(2)$, we get

\begin{align}
   (x-3)^2 + \bigg(\frac 35x - \frac 95 \bigg)^2 &= 16 \\
   (x-3)^2 + \dfrac{9}{25}(x-3)^2 &= 16 \\
   (x-3)^2 &= \dfrac{200}{17} \\
   x &= 3 \pm 10\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}} \\
   y &= 1 \pm 6\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}} \\
   (x,y) &\in \left\{
          \bigg(3 + 10\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}}, 1 + 6\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}} \bigg),
          \bigg(3 - 10\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}}, 1 - 6\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{17}} \bigg)
  \right\}
\end{align}

One solution gives you the coordinates of the closest point and the other gives you the coordinates of the furthest point.